# How to copy to unit test out-folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I have created a test project to test my WPF project.
One of my methods needs to read from a file, which is copied into the bin folder

```
C:\..\ProjectName\Bin\Debug\
```

when compiling. The method works fine, but when running the unitTest it searches for the file in

```
C:\..\ProjectName\TestResult\UserName_computerName-Date\Out\
```

How can I copy the file to that location when running the unit test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using MSTest?  If so, try the DeploymentItem attribute with the path to your test file:

```
[DeploymentItem(@"C:\vsprojects\MyProject\Tests\testdata\XmlContentFileOne.xml")]  
[TestMethod]  
public void MyTest()  
{  
  //test 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For this to work, I had to change Local.testSettings file, and enable the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way..
in VS 2010
Test Menu-->Edit Test Setting-->Local(local.testsetting)

Deployment attribute-- add the file or add the Directory which you required in Testing method
so at time of Test build VS automatically deploy the files and Directories in Out Directory of Test.